# Imports in python are static, any solution?

Tags: python

foo.py :

```
i = 10

def fi():
    global i
    i = 99
```

bar.py :

```
import foo
from foo import i

print i, foo.i
foo.fi()
print i, foo.i
```

This is problematic. Why does `i` not change when `foo.i` changes?

Comment: The output is as follows: 10 10 \n 10 99

Comment: the question is not really clear. Just use foo.i, what exactly is the problem? laziness?

Comment: This is a fairly clear beginners question. He wants i to be 99 after he calls foo.fi(). I think that what he is missing is the execution of the module. +1 to neutralize.

Comment: +1 good question; getting on top of this conceptis important to understand python, both mechanically and to help design more pythonic code

Comment: I'm with @hansen j: what's wrong with `foo.i`?

Comment: +1 people need to read this to understand why this is missthinking. And I made the mistake myself years ago :-)

Comment: Also with hasen j in that foo.i is the way to go... just disagree that the question is unclear or not worthwhile (corrected this comment... spelled your name wrong first time... sorry hasen j).

Comment: The problem, as I see it, with using foo.i directly is that it violates oo principals of encapsulation. It is better than just using i, that is true. Some modules are designed such that you have to use their 'foo.i', new modules should be designed with accessors and only export constants.

Comment: In Python,  you frequently access directly to parameters. Getter and setters are pretty rare for the basic stuff. For complex things, you often use property that seems to be class members : that's part of the culture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `import` does in `bar.py` is set up an identifier called `i` in the `bar.py` module namespace that points to the same address as the identifier called `i` in the `foo.py` module namespace.

This is an important distinction... `bar.i` is not pointing to `foo.i`, but rather to the same space in memory where the object `10` is held that `foo.i` happens to point to at the same time. In python, the variable names are not the memory space... they are the identifier that points to a memory space. When you import in bar, you are setting up a local namespace identifier.

Your code behaves as expected until `foo.fi()` is called, when the identifier `i` in the foo.py namespace is changed to point to the literal 99, which is an object in memory obviously at a different place than 10. Now the module-level namespace dict for `foo` has `i` identifying a different object in memory than the identifier `i` in bar.py.

Shane and rossfabricant have good suggestions on how to adjust your modules to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 8):

What Ross is saying is to restucture foo like so:

```
_i = 10

def getI():
    return _i

def fi():
    global _i
    _i = 99
```

Then you will see it works the way you want:

```
>>> import foo
>>> print foo.getI()
10
>>> foo.fi()
>>> print foo.getI()
99
```

It is also 'better' in the sense that you avoid exporting a global, but still provide read access to it.

Answer (score 3):

`i` inside `foo.py` is a **different** `i` from the one in `bar.py`. When in `bar.py` you do:

```
from foo import i
```

That creates a new `i` in `bar.py` that *refers to the same object* as the `i` in `foo.py`.

Your problem is: When you call `foo.fi()` and it does that:

```
i = 99
```

That assignment makes `foo.py`'s `i` point to another integer object (`99`). Integer objects are immutable themselves (thankfully) so it only changes what `foo.py`'s `i` is pointing to. Not `bar.py`'s `i`. `bar.py`'s `i` still points to the old object it was pointing before. (the integer immutable object `10`)

You can test what I am talking about by placing the following command in `bar.py`:

```
print foo.i
```

it should print `99`.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function instead of referencing a global variable.